# Redirect 301 Not Working properly codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have two links for a place.

link 1: http://www.myhappyjourney.com/Rae%20Bareli
link 2: http://www.myhappyjourney.com/Rae-Bareli

I want to redirect link 1 to link 2 permanently. All urls with space to with hyphen.

Tried the following code. But not working. It is putting index.php in the url.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Note: Project is in codeigniter.

Full .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.myhappyjourney\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myhappyjourney.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule for space to hyphen redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s.*)$" $1-$2 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.myhappyjourney\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myhappyjourney.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: It is working. But it is putting index.php in the url. That was the problem with the previous code also.

Comment: Facing one issue. It is replacing the image urls also. e.g. Rae Bareli.jpg to Rae-Bareli.jpg (which I don't want). Is there any solution?